# Name of the baroque music in the movie Lush Life (1993)?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, jazz, baroque

I'd like to know the name of the baroque piece in the [scene](https://youtu.be/GSYfFE_BOMo?t=2808)  where Al Gorky plays the recorder.

Comment: To help others who may be searching:  I've tried two things that didn't pan out: (1) looking at the end credits, which lists details for some of the jazz numbers but doesn't seem to mention this song and (2) a melody search on Musipedia (and the associated "contour search"):  http://www.musipedia.org/result.html?sourceid=melody-url&tx_mpsearch_pi1[submit_button]=Search&tx_mpsearch_pi1[pc]=lilydis%274+fis%274+ais%274+fis%274+gis%278+fis%278+f%278+dis%278+d%274+ais%274+fis%274+dis%274+gis%274+ais%278+b%278+fis%272+f%272+&filtertext=&coll=m&onlymatchfrom=0.3&ofs=90

Comment: Since it's not credited, it might be a composition made for this film (in baroque style).

Comment: What is a recorder flute? Do you mean recorder? Can you be sure that it's baroque?

Comment: Yes, I mean recorder. Have you watched the link ? They mention it's baroque.

Answer (score 1):

The original music in the movie was composed by [Lennie Niehaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennie_Niehaus), and, as Arsak suggested, that includes this baroque-style piece, according to [Sonya Jason](https://sonyajason.com/index.htm?hof/hofjeffgoldblum.htm&content), who writes that she was one of the clarinetists in that scene. I can't find evidence that the movie piece was anything but. For any more information, including answering your original question about the title, I suggest starting with his publisher(s) and/or estate.